# Install Fedora 17 to iSCSI Target, Boot from iSCSI Target

Tags: fedora, iscsi

I have installed Fedora 17 to an iSCSI target by:

1. Booting with the Fedora 17 ISO
2. Chose LiveCD so I could install iscsi-initiator-utils
3. Started the installer
4. Chose iSCSI target from native Fedora installer
5. Installed as normal

Using iPXE (gpxe/etherboot fork) to boot with `sanboot iscsi:HOSTIP::::TARGET:LUN`, but Fedora bombs after about 10 seconds with the following errors:

```
Cannot open font file True

dracut Warning: Unable to process initqueue
dracut Warning: /dev/disk/by-uuid/{UUID} does not exist

Dropping to debug shell

dracut:/#
```

A Redhat fellow from this [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=815333) suggested dracut-network (including the initramfs rebuild) and some kernel param voodoo, but I get the same errors.